# How to keep track of an ID (Primary) in different tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I'll start with an example, so that it is clear what I am trying to ask.

```
Templates
template_id, Name
1, Light Blue
2, Red
3, Sky Blue
4, Yellow
```

The template_id is primary and auto-increment.

```
Products
product_id, product_name, template_id
```

.

```
Users
user_id, user_name, template_id
```

.

```
Categories
category_id, category_name, template_id
```

There are 6+ tables more like this referencing to template_id.

The **default** template_id in all these tables is **zero** (which means no template is assigned)

I need a way to store these references somewhere so that if I try to delete a template my php application would check if it's in use or not. I know it's a kind of foreign key concept but I am not sure if I can have a zero value in a foreign key column so I am feeling a bit stuck. What would be your advise to resolve this issue? How do I keep track of where the template ID is in use in different tables.

**UPDATE**

I tried to add foreign key as suggested ...

```
ALTER TABLE `Templates`  
ADD CONSTRAINT `Templates_ibfk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (`template_id`) REFERENCES `Products` (`template_id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `Templates_ibfk_2` 
FOREIGN KEY (`template_id`) REFERENCES `Users` (`template_id`)
```

Where can I check if these have added? I tried look in structure of Templates table using PhpMyAdmin but can't find anything mentioning foreign keys in there ??

Comment: Don't use a `0` value for the template_id in products/users/categories, use `null`; then you'll have no problem with using foreign key constraints

Comment: Yes, I can change to Null. But are you saying to use foreign key after changing it to NULL then? Could you give an example please?

Comment: I __am__ saying to use foreign key constraints after changing it to null; then if you try to delete a template that is used, the constraint will prevent you from doing so

Answer (score 0):

Use Reference view in Mysql, This will be helps you to manage / Track the record automatically in future.

```
  ALTER TABLE `Templates`  ADD CONSTRAINT `Templates_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`template_id`) REFERENCES `Products` (`template_id`),ADD CONSTRAINT `Templates_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`template_id`) REFERENCES `Users` (`template_id`)
```

To know more about details, Read this [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: is t_Templates the same as "Templates" in my example above or is it a new table?

Comment: no I will edit. ALTER TABLE `Templates`  ADD CONSTRAINT `Templates_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`template_id`) REFERENCES `Products` (`template_id`),ADD CONSTRAINT `Templates_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`template_id`)

Comment: Ok one more ques - Do I also need to change individual template_id column in all the different tables to add a foreign key ? or I just have to alter "Templates" tables only and change the default to NULL in all other tables?

Comment: Actually If you adding the value of 2 in template_id in Products table without having template_id in Templates. Is the template_id Primary key in templates table?

Comment: Yes it's primary key in the templates table.

Comment: How primary key value default null you have alter default not null? Enough to alter in main table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60397/discussion-between-user3710266-and-punitha-subramani-v).

Answer (score 0):

I would use InnoDB for my tables, establish the foreign key restraints and let MySQL take care of the problem instead of trying to replicate this functionality programmatically.

i would also avoid using 0 for the default template and create a default (no template) which would be template_id = 1

keep 0 and/or -1 for errors.

Comment: Hi - do I need to set foreign keys on the parent table as suggested by "punitha subramani v" or It has to be individual columns in child tables??

Comment: once you have created your tables, the parent and child  tables must have  index for the fields.  then establish the RELATIONSHIPS by opening your child tables in STRUCTURE view and choosing the RELATIONSHIP viewer.  you will see dropdowns for every indexed field that you want.  you can then choose how deletions and updates propagate (cascade or restrict).